# Как дождаться выполнения нескольких http запросов?

Tags: angularjs, promise

Я хочу предоставить пользователю возможность загружать несколько файлов, каждый файл буду отправлять отдельным запросом, после выполнения всех запросов, необходимо выполнить запрос на получение всех итемов.

Для этого внес соответствующие изменения в свой код, проверять выполнение всех запросов решил делать через `Promise.all`

```
.then((item, attachments) => {
    let promises = [];
    attachments.forEach(attachment => {
        promises.push(addItem(item, attachment));        
    });
    return Promise.all(promises.map(promise => { promise.catch(e => console.log(e)); }));
})
.then(() => { return getIems(); })
.then(items => $scope.items = items);
```

Но, данный код не работает, запрос на получение итемов уходит на сервер до того как выполнятся все запросы.

Метод на клиенте для отправки файла на сервер упрощенно выглядит так:

```
function addItem(item, attachment){
    let url = '';
    return Upload.upload({
        url: url,
        data: {attachment: attachment, model: Upload.json(item) }
    });
}
```

где для [Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage), сторонняя библиотека.

на стороне сервера метод принимающий файл выглядит так:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddItem()
{
    try
    {
        //Здесь логика проверки и сохранения файла
        return Ok();
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Наверное, вот в этой строчке `promises.map(promise => { promise.catch(e => console.log(e)); })` у вас возращается пустой массив. Добавьте `return promise`;

Answer (score 0):

Используй сервис [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
.then((item, attachments) => {
    let promises = attachments.map(attachment => {
        return addItem(item, attachment));        
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
})
.then(() => {
    $scope.items = getIems()
})
.catch(console.error);
```